# Android: Firebase ChildEventListener() not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working in my app with Firebase and I tried to use onChildAdded() callback but I think I am doing something wrong because I get no response.

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
private FirebaseManager(Context context) {
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(context);
    Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    mFirebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
}
```

---

```
public void checkUsers() {
    Firebase checkRef = mFirebaseRef.child("/data/users/");
    // Also tried 
    // Firebase checkRef = mFirebaseRef.child("data").child("users");
    checkRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d(TAG,"New child added");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }


    });
}
```

In onCreate() of my MainActivity I authenticate the user and the call checkUsers(). After that I manually add a new user in database. But I get nothing in log.
This is the json structure:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. There was a `concurrency problem`. I called `checkUsers()` in `onCreate()` of the `MainActivity` but it needs to be called in `onAuthenticated()`, because the user was authenticated after the method `checkUsers()` tried to set listeners.

I got a LOG about the failure of accessing database:

```
W/SyncTree: Listen at / failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied
```

but didn't seen it because I was following a specific TAG with logcat Search.

Comment: This is indeed a common mistake: if you need to be authenticated to be allowed to read something, you should only attach the listener *after* then authentication has completed. An `onAuthenticated()` handler is perfect for that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am in the learning stage with android and Firebase is just the second BaaS I am working with. I tried Parse a month ago but the news made me to move on.